# Upload images to media library based on custom field

Tags: wordpress, curl, upload, media

I have just migrated from a custom built site. As I was not totally sure what I was doing, I created a custom field called featured_image and put a URL to an image in it for each post.

Now.

Is there a way, that I can loop through all of my posts and generate a thumbnail / featured image from the URL in the custom field?

Hope that makes sense!

**More info.**

I have moved 7000 posts, each post has a custom field that has a single url to an image in it.  I would like to take those urls and make them into the featured image for the associated posts.

I have a plugin that can take the first image in a post and as I republish, but that may not be practical for 7000!

Thanks

Comment: Wordpress already enables a featured image function, you just need to set it up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I found the answer by hacking apart another plugin.

First, I loop through postmeta table

```
$postid_list = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT distinct post_id FROM yars_postmeta WHERE meta_key='featured_image' ORDER BY post_id DESC LIMIT 10");
        if (!$postid_list){
                die('No posts with images were found.');
        }
        foreach ($postid_list as $v) {
            $post_id = $v->post_id;
            //$options['url_method'] = $url_method;
            echo fig_fetch_images($post_id).'<br/>';
        }
```

Then in a function I get the image and then upload it to the media library as well as set the featured image for the post id

```
function fig_fetch_images( $post_id ) { 
global $wpdb;
//Check to make sure function is not executed more than once on save

if ( defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) 
return;

if ( !current_user_can('edit_post', $post_id) ) 
return;

remove_action('publish_post', 'fetch_images');  

//$post = get_post($post_id);   
$first_image = '';
$key = 'featured_image';
$first_image = get_post_meta($post_id, $key, true);
$wpdb->query("update yars_postmeta set meta_key ='featured_image_uploaded'WHERE meta_key='featured_image' AND post_id=".$post_id);

if (strpos($first_image,$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'])===false) {

    //Fetch and Store the Image 

    $get = wp_remote_get( $first_image );

    $type = wp_remote_retrieve_header( $get, 'content-type' );

    $mirror = wp_upload_bits(rawurldecode(basename( $first_image )), '', wp_remote_retrieve_body( $get ) );


    //Attachment options

    $attachment = array(

    'post_title'=> basename( $first_image ),

    'post_mime_type' => $type

    );

    // Add the image to your media library and set as featured image

    $attach_id = wp_insert_attachment( $attachment, $mirror['file'], $post_id );

    $attach_data = wp_generate_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $first_image );

    wp_update_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $attach_data );

    set_post_thumbnail( $post_id, $attach_id );


    // re-hook this function

    add_action('publish_post', 'fetch_images');     

}
return ('Done post '. $post_id .' : '. $first_image);
```

}

The original plugin was Hotlink Image Cacher!

Comment: hey I am in the same situation i can see `FROM yars_postmeta WHERE meta_key='featured_image'` what is it `yars_postmeta` ?

Comment: Yars_postmeta will actually be different for you, I didn't realise when I posted this that the prefix could be found programmatically. Yours is probably something like wp_postmeta in the database. You get the prefix with $wpdb->prefix

Answer (score 0):

I think you should explain more. Do you have, inside loop of single.php, a function that returns the custom field as an HTML image tag ? If so, there are plugins that automatically generate the Post Thumbnail (Featured Thumbnail) from the first image in post or any custom post type.

Second, if you still don't have too much posts in your site, I think that adding a text custom field (which contains image urls) is not the best approach since you can create custom fields responsable of holding images if the built in default featured image field is not enough.

But please answer us first. Where and how are you going to use your thumbnails?? (explain more using a code). It will be better so that you get more help from the community.

Good luck, regards

Comment: Hi.Sadly I can't explain using code as I would not know what to put!! I am not a big PHP guy. However, I have added more details